# Confusion in n factor in the reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry

What will be the n-factor of $\ce{O2}$ in the reaction:

$$\ce{C4H10 + \frac{13}{2} O2 -> 4 CO2 + 5 H2O}$$

My tutor said it will be 26 but I am confused because he used stiochiometric coefficients in calculation too. Isn't n-factor for a mole or formula unit ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The definition of n-factor, what was it when it was introduced?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/152124/the-definition-of-n-factor-what-was-it-when-it-was-introduced)

Comment: No it doesn't.I am confused in this specific reaction.

Comment: Isn't n factor for 1 mol or a formula unit.My teacher taught it in equivalent  concept which main purpose is to calculate without using st coefficients.Here using the st coefficients just don't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some teachers do not accept equations containing non integers. They say that it is impossible to take half a molecule . So the real equation should be : $$\ce{2 C4H_{10} + 13 O2 -> 8 CO2 + 10 H2O}$$ Here the $n$ factory is $26$

**Edit**: In this reaction, it  may be admitted that the $\ce{C}$ and $\ce{H}$ atoms from the butane molecule $\ce{C4H10}$ are all at the oxidation number equal to zero. In the oxidation of butane, each $\ce{C}$ atom offers $4$ electrons to $\ce{O}$ atoms. So, in total, it makes $16$ electrons for the $4$ $\ce{C}$ atoms. Each H atom offers $1$ electron, in total $10$ electrons for $10$ $\ce{H}$ atoms. So one molecule $\ce{C4H10}$ offers $16 + 10 = 26$ electrons to $\ce{O}$ atoms. As a consequence, the factor $n$ is equal to $26$ per molecule $\ce{C4H10}$.

Comment: But isn't n factor (or valency factor as my teacher calls it) defined for 1 mol or formula unit only??

Comment: In this reaction, one can admit that $\ce{C4H10}$ contains Carbon atoms and Hydrogen atoms both at the oxidation number zero. Each carbon atom offers $4$ electrons, in total $16$ electrons for all carbon atoms. Each H atom offers $1$ electron, in total $10$ electrons for all hydrogen atoms. One molecule $\ce{C4H10}$ offers $16 + 10 = 26$ electrons to oxygen atoms. The factor $n$ is equal to $26$ per molecule $\ce{C4H10}$

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise you to go through [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/152613/130029) before reading through the rest of this post.

---

In the reaction
$$\ce{C4H10 + \frac{13}{2} O2 -> 4 CO2 + 5 H2O}$$

Let's see from the perspective of $\ce{O2}$
$$\ce{\frac{13}{2} O2 -> 4 CO2 + 5 H2O}$$

Initially the oxygen atom has oxidation state of zero, and in the water and carbon dioxide molecules the oxidation state is -2. So for each oxygen atom the number of electrons involved is 2.

n factor is not defined only for 1 mol only, it is defined based on the way the reaction is written and in this case it is written as $$\ce{\frac{13}{2} O2}$$ so 13 oxygen atoms are involved, giving the final answer as 26.

Comment: Difficult to understand how $13/2$ $\ce{O2}$ can produce $5$ $\ce{H2O}$

Comment: fixed the error, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Ah ok now I think I am beginning to understand.I was taught n factor in equivalent concept where we weren't using st coeffs.Thanks.